# MATLAB simulink set PID parameters

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to model a plant: 22.8/(s^2-3270) . Now I want to implement a PID controller to this. So I plan to follow the Ziegler Nichol's method.
By setting Kp as 145, I get sustained oscillations with a time period of about 1s
By setting Kp as 144, I get sustained oscillations with a time period of about 5s
By setting Kp as 143.5, I get sustained oscillations with a time period of about 30s
for Kp less than 143, i don't get any oscillations, but by minutely varying Kp below 143.5, the time period seems to increase significantly. 
So how exactly do I set the Ki and Kd parameters?

Comment: Ziegler Nichol cannot be used in an unstable system since it require slowly increasing the gain until instability is identified. You need to do something else

Comment: @rasman: you're right. don't know how i missed that.
So now I'll have to rephrase thus: how to set PID parameters for a system with 1 positive pole?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/pid-control.html

Answer (score -1):

`MATLAB` has a GUI that supports tuning `PID` parameters. Go to the command line and enter the following:

```
s = tf('s')

P = 22.8/(s^2 - 3270)

pidtool(P, 'pid')
```

That will open a GUI which shows you the default starting points based on default criteria (rise time, etc.). You can see the default gain values by clicking the 'parameters' button on the right hand side. You can then change the criteria to get updated gain values.

Note that this won't necessarily help if you have an unstable system or a poorly modeled transfer function.